# three.js website background set speed

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

My friend and I are working on a site, and we used three.js to make a background for it. There's a few sizing issues we're trying to figure out, so right now it looks best with about a 1300 x 800 window. The main problem we're having is that we can't figure out how to get the animation to stay at a set speed. It starts slow, then speeds up infinitely, which we don't want.

In the JS, I marked the speed controls that are causing the problem. I tried multiple different ways of doing the "if, else if, else if" stuff, and I tried multiple different number combinations and I can't get it to stay at a single speed. Every time I thought it would work, there was no animation. It didn't speed up or anything.

Also, if you're going to render it, it may be best to save the code in one folder as:

styles.css, index.html, and animation.js

**The Javascript**

```
var scene, camera, renderer, controls;
var geometry, material, plane,
  meshes = [];

var timeout;

var width = window.innerWidth,
  height = window.innerHeight;
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');

var init = function () {
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(80, width / height, .01, 2000);
  camera.position.set(0, -45, (height / 9));
  camera.rotation.x = .3;

  scene.fog = new THREE.FogExp2(0x222233, 0.001275);

  var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x121212);
  scene.add(ambientLight);

  var spotLight = new THREE.SpotLight(0xFFFFFF);
  spotLight.position.set(0, -25, 200);

  spotLight.castShadow = true;

  spotLight.shadowDarkness = 1;

  spotLight.shadowMapWidth = 1024;
  spotLight.shadowMapHeight = 1024;

  spotLight.shadowCameraNear = 0.01;
  spotLight.shadowCameraFar = 1000;
  spotLight.shadowCameraFov = 80;

  scene.add(spotLight);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true,
    alpha: true
  });
  renderer.setClearColor(0x222228);
  renderer.setSize(width, height);
  canvas.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry((width / 5), (height / 7), 13, 8);

  material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    // color: 0x03A9F4,
    color: 0x2196F3,
    shading: THREE.FlatShading
  });

  plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  meshes.push(plane);

  scene.add(plane);

  window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
};

function onWindowResize() {
  width = window.innerWidth;
  height = window.innerHeight;

  camera.aspect = width / height;
  camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

  camera.position.set(0, -45, (height / 9));
  canvas.style.height = height * .575 + "px";
  plane.geometry.width = (width / 5);
  plane.geometry.height = (height / 7);
  renderer.setSize(width, height);
};


// Animation speed controls

var inc = .02,
  rotation = 5;
var render = function () {
  requestAnimationFrame(render);

  updatePos();

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

  if (rotation > 5)
    inc = .005;
  else if (rotation < 5)
    inc = -.005;
 else if (rotation = 5.2)
    inc = -.02;

  rotation += inc;
};

// End of speed controls

var updatePos = function () {
  for (i = 0; i < plane.geometry.vertices.length; i++) {
    var vertex = plane.geometry.vertices[i];
    vertex.z = Math.sin(((vertex.x + rotation * rotation) + (vertex.y + rotation / rotation)) / 8 ) * 5 + 20;
  };
  geometry.dynamic = true;
  geometry.computeFaceNormals();
  geometry.computeVertexNormals();
  geometry.normalsNeedUpdate = true;
  geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
}

var derender = function () {
  for (i = 0; i < meshes.length; i++) {
      meshes[i].geometry.dispose();
      meshes[i].material.dispose();
      scene.remove(meshes[i]);
  };
};

Math.range = function (min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
};

window.onload = function () {
  canvas.style.height = height * .575 + "px";
  init();
  render();
  // setInterval(updatePos, 150);
};

window.onbeforeunload = function () {
  derender();
};
```

**THE CSS**

```
/* Misc Global */
html {
  width: 100%;
}
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', Arial, Sans-Serif;
  background-color: #E5E5E5;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #343434;
  font-size: 1.075em;
}
a {
  color: #2196F3;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 700;
  opacity: .8;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
  opacity: 1;
}
p {
  text-indent: 1em;
}

/* Header and Stuff */
.banner {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
  box-shadow: 0px -4px 6px #9E9E9E;
}
#title {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 200;
  font-size: 4em;
  letter-spacing: .6em;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: inherit;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  color: #FAFAFA;
  margin-top: 3.5%;
  opacity: .98;
}
#phrase {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #F0F0F0;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 2.2em;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 14%;
  letter-spacing: .375em;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: .8;
  font-style: oblique;
}
#canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  opacity: .88;
  z-index: 0;
}

/* Begin page content */
.content {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}
.mission-statement {
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 400;
}

/* Previews */
#previews {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.preview {
  width: 330px;
  height: 240px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 35px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.preview-title {
  font-size: 1.2em;
  margin: 10px;
}
.preview img {
  border-radius: 2px;
  opacity: .98;
  margin-left: 45px;
  margin-right: 45px;
  width: 240px;
  height: 120px;
}
.preview-text {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 5px;
}

/* Recent Projects */
#recent-projects {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  background: #C0C0C0;
}
#rpr-title {
  width: 16%;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #535353;
  color: #EEEEEE;
  float: left;
  margin-top: -.8em;
  margin-left: 42%;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

/* Recent Posts */
#recent-posts {
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
}
#rpo-title {
  width: 16%;
  padding: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #535353;
  color: #EEEEEE;
  float: left;
  margin-top: -.8em;
  margin-left: 42%;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

/* Footer */
#footer {
  width: 96%;
  background-color: #D0D0D0;
  padding: 2%;
  font-size: .8em;
  opacity: .85;
}
.ft-el {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.ft-heading {
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

**The HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:500,900,300,700,400,100' rel='stylesheet'>
    <title>Cryptocosm Developers</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Cryptocosm Developers, Samuel Steele, Devin Fowler">
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r71/three.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="banner">
      <a id="title" href="/index.html">CRYPTOCOSM</a>
      <div id="phrase">Find New Worlds</div>
      <div id="canvas"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
      <br>
      <div id="previews">
        <div class="preview">
          <div class="preview-title">We love code, a lot</div>
          <img id="editor" src="img/editor.gif">
          <div class="preview-text">We strive to create optimized code by constantly refining it, keeping speed and size in mind.</div>
        </div>
        <div class="preview">
          <div class="preview-title">Attention to detail</div>
          <!-- @TODO: Animate detail.png to zoom with magnify glass to the corner of the card -->
          <img id="detail" src="img/detail.png">
          <div class="preview-text">We don't fret the little things because it can't be afforded. When designing a page, every pixel has meaning.</div>
        </div>
        <!-- @TODO: Think of some fake bullshit to put in this last **preview** -->
        <div class="preview">
          <div class="preview-title">Lorem Ipsum</div>
          <img id="lorem" src="img/.png">
          <div class="preview-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam sed pretium tortor.</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <br><br><br>
      <div id="recent-projects">
        <div id="rpr-title">RECENT PROJECTS</div>
      </div>
      <br><br><br><br>
      <div id="recent-posts">
        <div id="rpo-title">RECENT BLOG POSTS</div>
      </div>
      <br><br>
      <div id="footer">
        <div id="ft-contact" class="ft-el">
          <p class="ft-heading">CONTACT:</p>
          <p>Samuel Steele</p>
          <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="mailto:steelesam72@gmail.com?subject:Contact%20Cryptocosm">steelesam72@gmail.com</a></p>
          <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="//twitter.com/Cryptoc1">@Cryptoc1</a></p>
          <p>Devin Fowler</p>
          <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="mailto:fowlerd11@gmail.com?subject:Contact%20Cryptocosm">fowlerd11@gmail.com</a></p>
          <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="//twitter.com/DevinFowler11">@DevinFowler11</a></p>
        </div>
        <div id="ft-git" class="ft-el">
          <p class="ft-heading">GITHUB:</p>
          <p>Samuel Steele</p>
          <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="//github.com/cryptoc1">Cryptoc1</a></p>
          <!-- <p>Devin Fowler</p>
          <p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="//github.com/fowlerd11">Fowlerd11</a></p> -->
          <p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="animation.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: Your animation should be based on some type of timer function, either Date.now() or performance.now

Comment: a jsfiddle or similar would help read the source

Comment: I made a jsfiddle of it: https://jsfiddle.net/o3okhLoy/